# html css creating link to background

Tags: html, css

I'm an iOS developer and not a web developer.  I'm trying to create my website to promote my apps and am trying to attach a link to the background image defined in CSS as #hero.  I did some researching and found some examples where the css defines the background as .photo with the associated properties...but my structure is laid out with the # and multiple sections.  I've tried experimenting with different combinations like a blind person in the dark and couldn't manage to get anything working in the way I need it.  Looking for some help.

```
  <!-- ======= Hero Section ======= -->
  <section id="hero" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
     
    
    <div class="hero-container" data-aos="fade-in">
   <a href="http://www.google.com" title="NEED LINK" id="Hero??????">Hero</a>

   
    </div>
  </section><!-- End Hero -->
```

CSS COde below

```
.header {
    border-bottom:1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.header a {
    display: block;
    background-image: url("./images/embouchure.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:160px;
    padding-left:280px;
    padding-top:50px;
    width:470px;
    color: #eaeaea;
}

#hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("../img/hero-bg.jpg") top center;
  background-size: cotain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}



#hero:before {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(5, 13, 24, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#hero .hero-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  min-width: 300px;
}

#hero h1 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  color: #fff;
}

#hero p {
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

#hero p span {
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #149ddd;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  #hero {
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #hero h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 36px;
  }
  #hero h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve it by

javascript

```
$(".hero-container").click(function() {
     window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
     return false;
 });
```

or you can try like

```
<a href="https://google.com">
    <div class="hero-container">
        anything
    </div>
 </a>
```

Or, you could set a data-* attribute on the

```
  <div data-location="https://google.com">
```

and do like:

```
   window.location = $(".hero-container").data("location");
```